# Integrate finished ASP.NET Website in Sitefinity CMS

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, sitefinity

Is there a way to integrate a finished ASP.NET Website into Sitefinity CMS? Including the master page and all stuff.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it can help:http://www.sitefinity.com/devnet/forums/sitefinity-3-x/set-up-installation/integrate-sitefinity-with-existing-application.aspx

Comment: What version are you going to be working with?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "quick integration" type of solution. That said, taking an existing site and integrating it with Sitefinity isn't very difficult. You would need to:

1. [Download and get an installation
   running](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/installation-and-administration-guide/install-sitefinity/downloading-and-installing-sitefinity)
2. Take your master pages and [turn them into
   templates](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/designer-s-guide/page-templates/creating-a-template-using-master-pages)
3. [Create your pages](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/user-guide/pages) and [add your content](http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/user-guide/website-content)